# Adjusting the environment for each column in a tabular

Tags: tables, environments

I keep wanting to adjust the environment for every cell in a particular column in tabular, but have not found an easy way to do do this. I am hoping I can do this at the beginning of the table when I designate the alignment of each column. In the code below I would like to make the Relative Frequency  column be in math mode and color code each type of frequency without having to do that in every cell. I have found a few work arounds, but they are very specific and cumbersome. I would like to be able to make varying adjustments not just change the color or enter math mode but also potentially make a column bold or italic etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor} 

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}

\hline

Platelet & &  Relative & Percent & Cumulative \\\

Count & Freqency & Frequency & Freqency & Frequency \\\

\hline

100-199 & 27 & 27/150=9/50  & 18\\% & 27 \\\

\hline

200-299 & 93 & 31/50 & 62\\% & 120 \\\

\hline

300-399 & 28 & 14/75 & 18.67\\% & 148 \\\

\hline

400-499 & 0 & 0 & 0\\% & 148 \\\

\hline

500-599 & 2 & 1/75 & 1.33\\% & 150 \\\

\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you describe the conditions that would influence the colour (and other formatting)? You can consider moving to the [`tabularray` package](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) and its `tblr` environment, where conditions and formatting of elements within the table (row, column or cell) can be specified in the preamble rather than on a columnar basis only (which is typical for `tabular`).